# How separate target and source nodes which have the same name in Excel file?

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I'm doing a protein-protein interaction network.

In some cases, a source and a target protein have the same names (though they're not actually the same, but they have the same name)

When loading it into Cytoscape, only one node shows with that name. I technically need two nodes that show with that name, since they're separate proteins.

Answer (score 0):

Cytoscape desktop doesn't really care about name uniqueness, but when you import your file, there has to be **some** unique column that can be used to distinguish between two different nodes.  It can be a column with uniprot identifiers, or entrez, or ensembl, or even a custom node number you've made up.  Once you have your network loaded, you can then point to the column that contains your name for visualization.